# Woocommerce - Get the best selling category (taxonomy)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am in need of a function that prints out categories from top to bottom with best selling to worst selling. I've only managed to get this to work with products. Can someone assist me in how to do so or maybe already have that function stored somewhere? Thanks in advance :)

The products are a subscription btw. Don't know if that matters.

Here's the frontend part (which is hardcoded) to give an example of final results that I'm going for:

[image]

This is the code for single best selling item. If we can modify this to get the best selling products then that would be awesome!

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
global $product; ?>
<div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) 
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); 
        else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="product placeholder Image" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>

<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I guess you would have to loop over _all_ products, get the category/categories they are in - and then sum up the `total_sales` value per category, so that you can then sort the categories by those summed-up values afterwards. Not sure how efficicent this is gonna be, depends on the number of products and categories, I suppose. This might be a case, where you’d be better off with a custom SQL query, rather than relying on WP’s default querying mechanism.

Comment: @CBroe Indeed you are correct. I'm although not very good at sql and as I'm alone on this I'll have to do it the sqlquery way. I've managed to collect counts of orders by category ids by doing as you said. Loop through every order, get the product, get the term of the product etc.

Comment: This might be something you want to consider scheduling as a cron job, so that the results are calculated once in a while, rather than on every page load.  As @CBroe was saying, it's an inefficient query, and will definitely take some time to execute, since you have to loop through each order item and calculate best seller, then show the category list based on that result.

Comment: @HowardE or hook into the Woocommere order processing, so that it gets updated whenever a product gets sold. Combining it with the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache the results might also be a good idea then.

Comment: Yes @CBroe I like the idea of caching very slow queries, either with Transients or even a serialized `wp_options`. Having it update like you are saying, on order processing would be more a more efficient way to update the stored data once it's initially calculated. It might actually be even more efficient to save as a new table, with columns `product_id, product_cat_id , number_sold` so for the archive, `get_queried_object()`, followed by `SELECT id from 'new_table' where product_cat = $taxid ORDER by number_sold` then loop through that, and output $product for each.

Comment: @HowardE, yeah, there’s multiple possible ways, depends a bit on personal preferences, I’d say. Adding extra tables to a WP setup is something I’m always a bit reluctant about though. Some ful-fledged plugin doing this is one thing, but for something rather “small” like this, I would try and avoid the effort that comes with setting this up properly, so that it is easily portable to a different installation etc. […]

Comment: […] Storing this as meta data on the category entities themselves might be a middle-ground compromise of sorts. We use ACF on most of our projects anyway, so I would add a field to the categories, and store the number of sold products in there. Then the usual WP_Query mechanisms to sort by a meta data field can be used, to get them in the correct order. And even functions like `get_categories` allow to modify the query arguments via a filter, so it could easily be “injected” into default functionality this way.

Comment: Yea. I've experienced before that loading would take forever because of me being stupid. I've found and mofified a sql query so it works to my needs. Currently working on it but it seems to works so far.

Thanks for the advices everyone! :D